# Getting two numbers from STDIN

Tags: input, output, racket, evaluation

I want to get two numbers from STDIN and print the sum of them to STDOUT. The following code is my solution:

```
#lang racket
(displayln (+ (string->number (string-trim (read-line)))
              (string->number (string-trim (read-line)))))
```

If the input is

```
1
2
```

Sometimes the output is `3` as expected, but sometimes the output is:

```
+: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #f
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   2
  context...:
   sum.rkt: [running body]
```

Why is that?

## Edit 1

As shown in the following picture:

[image: example]

## Edit 2

I wrote the following code to explore the behaviour of my program:

```
#lang racket

(displayln "Input:")
(define s1 (string-trim (read-line)))
(define s2 (string-trim (read-line)))

(displayln "Output:")
(displayln (string->list s1))
(displayln (string->list s2))
(define n1 (string->number (string-trim s1)))
(define n2 (string->number (string-trim s2)))
(displayln n1)
(displayln n2)
(displayln (+ n1 n2))
```

My computer is slow, so the `Input:` line needs some time to come out. If I wait until the line shows up before I type the inputs, the program will behave as I expect:

[image: example]

But if I don't wait for the `Input:` line and type in my inputs directly, sometimes the error will happen:

[image: example]

So now my questions are:

1. Does it mean that the error happens because Racket is not initialized yet?
2. What does `R` mean?
3. In the error case, why is the first input correctly interpreted as `1`, but the second input wrongly interpreted as `R`?

(I'm running Racket `v6.1.1` under `Winodws 7 Pro SP1`)

Comment: If you enter anything that's not a number (even a line break) your code will fail with the error reported.

Comment: Thank you, @ÓscarLópez . But I think my inputs are the same every time, as shown in the added screenshot.

Comment: Looks like a problem with whitespaces, but it's weird because youre doing `string-trim`. Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: When entering the numbers, did you ever use backspaces? If the failed cases involved backspaces, it could be because the input is being sent to Racket as-is (e.g., "1`^H`2", where `^H` refers to the backspace character).

Comment: Thanks, @ÓscarLópez and Chris. I added some additional explorations about my program. I think the error happens because of the initializaton of Racket. But I still have some questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `(read)` to read numbers, assuming you can rely on sane input (i.e., if it's actually going to be numbers and not garbage or, worse, massive S-expressions). Thus your code would be:

```
(displayln (+ (read) (read)))
```

Comment: And what if I don't want numbers, but strings?